# Delete seconds, milliseconds and microseconds from a boost ptime

Tags: c++, datetime, boost

I would like to construct a new `boost::posix_time::ptime` from an existing `ptime`, by only conserving the year, month, day, hour and minute.
Is there any solution?

EDIT: Thanks to Rudolfs Bundulis, I found a solution which works:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp> 

using namespace boost::posix_time; 

int main()
{ 
    const ptime time(microsec_clock::local_time());
    const time_duration time_of_day = time.time_of_day(); 
    const ptime time2(time - microseconds(time_of_day.total_microseconds()) + hours(time_of_day.hours()) + minutes(time_of_day.minutes()));

    std::cout << "time 1: " << time  << std::endl;
    std::cout << "time 2: " << time2 << std::endl;
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% sure, since I'm also new to boost but I think this could do it:

```
boost::posix_time::ptime time(boost::posix_time::second_clock::local_time());
boost::posix_time::time_duration time_of_day = time.time_of_day();
time_of_day -= boost::posix_time::seconds(time_of_day.seconds());
boost::posix_time::ptime time2(time.date(), time_of_day);
```

Comment: Thank you! Your solution correctly deletes the seconds, but not the milli/microseconds. I adapted your solution.

#include <iostream>
#include <boost\date_time\posix_time\posix_time.hpp>

using namespace boost::posix_time;

int main()
{
    ptime time(microsec_clock::local_time());
 time_duration time_of_day = time.time_of_day();
 ptime time2(time - microseconds(time_of_day.total_microseconds()) + hours(time_of_day.hours()) + minutes(time_of_day.minutes()));
}
    return 0;
}

Comment: Damn, i was so close to being right - i thought that the seconds part holds all the lower partitions a well:) Maybe I at least deserve a vote up :D

Answer (score 1):

To round to seconds and milliseconds (removing offset of ms and us):

```
namespace b_pt = boost::posix_time;
// existing ptime which has to be rounded
b_pt::ptime existing_pt;

// rounding to seconds
b_pt::ptime rounded2sec(existing_pt.date(), b_pt::seconds(existing_pt.time_of_day().total_seconds()));

// rounding to milliseconds
b_pt::ptime rounded2msec(existing_pt.date(), b_pt::milliseconds(existing_pt.time_of_day().total_milliseconds));
```